# In CMake, how does CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX work?

Tags: cmake

The following code prints nothing

```
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(glog/logging.h GLOG_INCLUDE)
IF(GLOG_INCLUDE)
   MESSAGE("YY")
ENDIF(GLOG_INCLUDE)
```

But I have the following environment variable set:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
```

And, "ls /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h" returns the file.

I tried using

```
include_directories( "/usr/local/include" )
```

but GLOG_INCLUDE remains undefined after (logging.h remains not found.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the CheckIncludeFileCXX.cmake. It should be in a directory in your cmake installation (I have it in /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules).

This file states:

```
# The following variables may be set before calling this macro to
# modify the way the check is run:
#
#  CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS = string of compile command line flags
#  CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS = list of macros to define (-DFOO=bar)
#  CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES = list of include directories
#
```

So you can try setting this variable before caling the command, like this:

```
set (CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "/usr/local/include")
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(glog/logging.h GLOG_INCLUDE)
IF(GLOG_INCLUDE)
   MESSAGE("YY")
ENDIF(GLOG_INCLUDE)
```